# Is it possible to define a variable which type is depends on input in Golang

Tags: go

Learning `Go` and try to write an App which take bit depth as input, when `bitDepth == 8`, define a varable as `var y []byte`, When `bitDepth == 10`, define a variable `var y []uint16`

What's the right way to do it in Go?

Comment: The declared type of a variable can't depend on runtime values. You don't say what problem you're trying to solve, but https://godoc.org/image#Image is probably relevant -- even if you can't use Image directly, its source code may be useful.

Comment: @PaulHankin I have a quick look at the image package, it looks like only support 8 bits (uint8) pixel data. Don't have solution to support 10 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are no generics in go, you will still have to do type assertions if you use an empty interface i.e. `interface{}`.

The best option is to define an interface that provides all of the functionality you need, and implement it for all the datatypes you need to wrap.

```
package main

type SliceWrapper interface {
    Slice(start, end int) SliceWrapper
    Index(index int) int
}

func NewSlice(bitDepth int) SliceWrapper {
    switch bitDepth {
    case 8:
        return make(Uint8Wrapper)
    case 16:
        return make(Uint16Wrapper)
    }
}

type Uint8Wrapper []uint8

func (u Uint8Wrapper) Slice(s, e int) SliceWrapper {
    return u[s:e]
}

func (u Uint8Wrapper) Index(i int) int {
    return u[i]
}

type Uint16Wrapper []uint16

func (u Uint16Wrapper) Slice(s, e int) SliceWrapper {
    return u[s:e]
}

func (u Uint16Wrapper) Index(i int) int {
    return u[i]
}
```

You will need more functionality than that I am sure, but it is way cleaner than throwing `interface{}` around everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

one way is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func virtualVar(bitDepth int) interface{} {
    var v interface{}
    switch bitDepth {
    case 8:
        y := []byte{1, 2}
        v = y
    case 16:
        y := []uint16{12345, 11000}
        v = y
    }
    return v
}

func main() {
    a := virtualVar(8)
    b := virtualVar(16)
    fmt.Println(a) //[1 2]
    fmt.Println(b) //[12345 11000]
}
```